# Continuity of monotone increasing function

Tags: continuity

Let f(x) be monotone increasing. Define $S=\{x|c \leq f(x) \leq d\}$. Show that S must be a single interval.

I understand this intuitively and graphically, but don't know how to prove this formally. Please help with a proof strategy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: you need to show that if $x_1\in S$ and $x_3\in S$ and $x_1<x_2<x_3$, then $x_2\in S$.

Comment: Hmm, ok, but would this prove that there is only one interval, and not multiple ones such as for sin or cos?

Comment: Yes!  Draw two pictures on the real line to see why: (1) an interval; (2) two separate intervals.  Is the statement I suggested you prove true in both cases?

Comment: Hmm, but if I take x1 and x2 from the same interval and a larger x3 from another repeating part of the interval, wouldn't the result also hold?

Comment: How could that happen?  Give me an example.  I don't think I understand what you mean.

Comment: Something like this: ![enter image description here][1]


  [1]: http://i.stack.imgur.com/Kmzvk.png

Comment: But that doesn't always work: you could have taken $x_2$ in between the two blue parts.  This proves that the blue parts do not form an interval.

Comment: Ok, I see, thank you!